# Child control properties of a user control are not persistent

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a usercontrol and when I set properties on the child controls, such as left and width they get forgotten.

I made an image to illustrate this but it appears they stopped allowing images.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Label As imsLabel
    Get
        Return lbl
    End Get
End Property

Public Property LabelText As String
    Get
        Return lbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        lbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Dropdown As ComboBox
    Get
        Return cbo
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property ColorBox As imsPictureBox
    Get
        Return pic
    End Get
End Property
```

When I draw the control on the form it appears as I designed it.  When I move the picturebox and combobox over 10 and increase the size of the label by 10 using the properties window it renders correctly on the screen.  When I run the app or close the form and reopen it the changes are lost.

Anyone know how to make them persist?  I was using the properties above.  Do I need to expose each property directly?

thanks

Comment: Setting runtime properties is not the same as using the designer.  You could save those properties as settings

Comment: I am setting the properties in the designer.  They do not persist.